# Grails 3.0.x AJAX tags are not listed in documention

Tags: ajax, grails

What happened to the AJAX tags (remoteFunction, formRemote, submitToRemote...) in Grails 3.0. The documentation does not list them, at all. Does Grails 3.0.x deprecate them?.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX related tags have been removed in Grails 3.x. This was discussed for years leading up to this release.

Comment: Thanks, Joshua. I just started using Grails just a few months ago.

Comment: what is the best practice now for achieving the same functionality?

Comment: Typically most people use the AJAX functions from a library such as jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I found the answer in the documentation.

"... other Ajax related tags have been deprecated and will be removed from a future version of Grails. Applications may provide their own Ajax tags and/or Javascript plugins may provide Ajax tags of their own."